# Failed to resolve: com.android.support:library-aar:25.0.0?

Tags: android

Good evening, can you give me the solution to this problem
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sz1uZ.png)

Comment: There is nothing with that name in the Android Support library.

Comment: @CommonsWare 
How i can solve this problem????

Comment: Remove that line from your `build.gradle` file. Again, there is nothing with that name. I do not know what you are trying to add to your project.

Comment: Thank you man ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just click that text when you see that warning. If nothing dowload then delete this library to your gradle .

> If you want to add support library
>
> 1)Start the Android SDK Manager.
>
> 2)In the SDK Manager window, scroll to the end of the Packages list,
>   find the Extras folder and, if necessary, expand to show its contents.
>
> 3)Select the Android Support Repository item.
>
> 4)Click the Install packages... button.

then try this

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'